# How can I pass a parameter obtained using a jQuery.get call to another jQuery.get call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to build a simple html page that displays data obtained from csv files on GitHub. To do that, I used jQuery's .get calls in order to get the full text from the URL and then manipulated it through jQuery-CSV.
The data I'm using comes from https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/tree/master/dati-andamento-nazionale.

The organization managing the repository always uses `dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale-latest.csv` as filename for newest data, so I just use

```
    var national_csv = null; 
        jQuery.get(LATEST_URL, function (data) {
        national_csv = $.csv.toObjects(data)[0];
    }, 'text');
```

The issue comes when I have to get data from the day before (in order to compare it with current data). URLs for past info have a format like this: `dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale-YYYYMMDD.csv`.

A solution I came up with was using the date parameter in the CSV file I'd just get (since it's included along with the rest of the data) and manipulate it through Date() in order to get the date of the past day, and then create a function that would return this date, as a string, included in the url.

```
function yesterdayURL(date) {
    return "dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale-"+dayBeforeAsString(date)+".csv";
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do the following:

```
var national_csv = null;
var today = null;
jQuery.get(LATEST_URL, function(data) {
    national_csv = $.csv.toObjects(data)[0];
    today = national_csv.data;
}).then(jQuery.get(yesterdayURL(today), function() {/*do stuff*/}));
```

Though, it seems the value of `today` is still null. How can I solve this?

P.S.: I'm pretty new to Ajax and asynchronous programming, but I've been trying hard to solve this issue despite failing, so I'm sorry if the question appears to be dumb. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will either need to define a variable outside of the two AJAX calls so you can reference it within both or nest the calls. If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty thank you for your reply. Do I need to open a new thread in order to follow these  guidelines or should I include the example in the comments?

Comment: I would advise taking the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour it will help you see how to Edit a post and how to ask a question with an example.